# Python MySQLdb: How to get the result of a sql select having a group by into a dict?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

I have a sql query like this running in python:

```
select sum(a), date from table group by date
```

Then I execute this query and get the result:

```
    cursor.execute (query, queryParameters)
    rows = cursor.fetchall();
```

As expected rows is an array:

```
    (('2014-05-13', Decimal('1.6666666667')), ('2014-05-14', Decimal('33.0151515152')), ('2014-05-15', Decimal('66.4850000000')), ('2014-05-16', Decimal('49.8274022154')), ('2014-05-18', Decimal('4.0000000000')))
```

But i want it as an hash, where the date is the key and the sum is the value(every row is a key-value pair). And since it is a group by date, it makes sense to have it in a hash. Something like this:

```
{ '2014-05-13' => '1.6666666667', '2014-05-14' => '33.0151515152'....}
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of the fields and pass `fetchall()` results to [`dict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-dict):

```
query = "select date, sum(a) from table group by date"
cursor.execute (query, queryParameters)
result = dict(cursor.fetchall())
```

Demo:

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> data = (('2014-05-13', Decimal('1.6666666667')), ('2014-05-14', Decimal('33.0151515152')), ('2014-05-15', Decimal('66.4850000000')),
>>> dict(data)
{'2014-05-18': Decimal('4.0000000000'), '2014-05-13': Decimal('1.6666666667'), '2014-05-15': Decimal('66.4850000000'), '2014-05-14': Decimal('33.0151515152'), '2014-05-16': Decimal('49.8274022154')}
```